# SQL group by values stored in arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, group-by, orientdb

I use OrientDB.
I have a table like this:

```
 NAME | CATEGORIES
-------------------
  N1  |   [A,B]
  N2  |   [C]
  N3  |   [C,A]
  N4  |   [A,B]
```

And I would like to build a query that returns a list of categories, and for each category a list of related names, like this:

```
 CATEGORY |   NAMES
-----------------------
    A     | [N1,N3,N4]
    B     | [N1,N4]
    C     | [N2,N3]
```

If "categories" wasn't an array, I could achieve it with:

```
SELECT
  Categories as Category,
  set(Name) as Names
FROM Table
GROUP BY Categories
```

But, being Categories arrays, this is what I get:

```
 CATEGORY |  NAMES
--------------------
   [A,B]  | [N1,N4]
    [C]   | [N2]
   [C,A]  | [N3]
```

What query should I rather write?

Comment: It would be much easier if you use two classes and connect them with edges. Can you change your structure to make the most from graph db?

Comment: What kind of data-type are you using for CATEGORIES? Is it a list?

Comment: Categories is type Embedded. I could move the categories in a new class and create edges. It'd actually make sense, it's true. I just never needed to do anything complex with them until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your structure with this command

```
create class test extends v
create property test.name string
create property test.categories embeddelist string

insert into test(name,categories) values ("N1",["A","B"]),("N2",["C"]),("N3",["C","A"]),("N4",["A","B"])
```

[image]

and I used this query

```
select categories,$a.name as name from (select distinct(categories) as categories from (select categories  from test order by categories unwind categories))
let $a = (select name from test where categories contains $parent.$current.categories)
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro! Looks like that's the solution. I would have had no idea how to build this type of query. I'll use this for now, but I think I'll follow @Oleksandr suggestion soon and move categories on a separate vertex